# database connection into class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

Using this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect
(
    $db_host,
    $db_user,
    $db_pwd
) or die ("FATAL ! : The server ".$db_host." is not responding to ".$db_user."!");
```

how to get the **$db** value into this class (from include "class.php") - without errors ;-)

```
class User
{
    public $db;
    public $id;

    public function getUser()
    {
        if($this->id)
        {
            $sql = "
            SELECT
                users.*
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                users.u_id='".$this->id."'
            ";
            $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
            $user_row = mysqli_fetch_object($db, $res);
            return $user_row;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    } // end class User
```

All I get is - well, nothing. Exept my main page loads empty... If I stop using the class, all is well (exept no data for the user is shown ;-))

Comment: Honestly, just create a database class and extend these models off it.  No need for these extra steps. OR if you have multiple databases, setup a `singleton` or `factory` pattern and call it statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you instantiate the class (User), if you have already assigned the variable ($db)...  you can do

```
$user = new User;
$user->db = $db;
$user->getUser();
```

yes AND inside your class when you are referencing properties of the class from its methods, use the `$this` notation...  i.e. change `$db` to `$this->db`

that should work.  you mentioned something about suppressing errors, that is a different issue.  I am unsure what your goal is, but normal exception handling prior to the class's instantiation would be adequate.

Comment: Worked like a charm.
I am of course aware of a need for a more Classy (get it ;-)) correct method.
Will be in a **next** release ..

Comment: you should note some of the classes written in other answers, I stuck only to what I thought the question to be.  they are right though in trying to move the connect to inside the class.  It is a more complete solution.  glad you got what you were looking for tho.

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate your class, and you must use the `$this` operator to access class members. Futhermore, it is better to inject parameters on construction and usage:

```
class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
       $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        if($id)
        {
            $sql = "
            SELECT
                users.*
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                users.u_id=" . (int)$id ;

            $res = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
            $user_row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->db, $res);
            return $user_row;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
$user = new User($db);
$userdata = $user->getUser(2);
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_object($db, $res); this also need $this